# LaTex font not found after upgrading linuxmint

Tags: fonts, packages, texlive, linux, texmf

I can't get working the font "Comicneue" with LaTex since I upgraded my linuxmint version. All was working fine before the upgrade.

I have the package Comicneue I downloaded from CTAN in ~/texmf/tex/latex/local/, I ran texhash, but have still an emergency stop when I try to compile a tex file width LaTex->dvi->dvi2ps->ps2pdf.

Here is a example tex file :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[default]{comicneue}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Here is the output I get :

```
 *****
*****     LaTeX output: 
*****     cd "/home/erwan/Bureau/test"
*****     latex -interaction=nonstopmode test.tex
*****
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-french/french.ldf))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/scalefnt.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/home/erwan/texmf/tex/latex/local/comicneue/tex/comicneue.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ly1/ly1enc.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ly1enc.dfu))))
(/home/erwan/texmf/tex/latex/local/comicneue/tex/T1ComicNeue-TLF.fd)
kpathsea: Running mktextfm ComicNeue-tlf-t1
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation C for ComicNeue-tlf-t1.
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input ComicNeue-tlf-t1
This is METAFONT, Version 2.71828182 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded base=mf)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf ComicNeue-tlf-t1

! I can't find file `ComicNeue-tlf-t1'.
<*> ...g:=1; ; nonstopmode; input ComicNeue-tlf-t1
                                                  
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...g:=1; ; nonstopmode; input ComicNeue-tlf-t1
                                                  
Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: ComicNeue-tlf-t1.log: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input ComicNeue-tlf-t1' failed to make ComicNeue-tlf-t1.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font T1/ComicNeue-TLF/m/n/12=ComicNeue-tlf-t1 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric 
(TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.15 \begin{document}
                     
(./test.aux) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ly1/ly1ptm.fd)
Missing character: There is no ^^V in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no T in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!
[1] (./test.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on test.dvi (1 page, 188 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Do you have any idea what I could try to fix this?

Thanks
Erwan

Comment: why did you install manually? It is in texlive 2022 and your example worked directly for me on windows.

Comment: With Linux and up-to-date TeX Live 2023 or last version of TeX Live 2022 it also works directly after adding `\documentclass{article}` as first line …

Comment: Update the TeX font map using the `updmap` command

Comment: Check that the required font files are present in the correct location:

`kpsewhich ComicNeue-tlf-t1.mf`
`kpsewhich ComicNeue-tlf-t1.tfm`
`kpsewhich T1ComicNeue-TLF.fd`

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your replyes. 
This font seems to be included in my version of texLive, as I just checked.
Sorry I forgot to copy the ```\documentclass``` command but it was there in my file.
I ran the updmap command.
I checked the presence of required font files width kpsewhich : the command returned /home/erwan/texmf/tex/latex/local/comicneue/tex/T1ComicNeue-TLF.fd for the last one but nothing for the two others. Though, these files are present in /home/erwan/texmf/tex/latex/local/comicneue/fonts/

Comment: If any of the files are not found, try reinstalling the comicneue package or manually copy the missing files to the appropriate directories.

Comment: Or run this command `sudo mktexlsr` which will update the TexLive Database

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to reinstall the package. I can't find the two files `.mf`and `.tfm` in the package I downloaded. I tried `mktexlsr`, then `updmap`and here is what I got :

`$ sudo updmap-sys --force --enable Map=comicneue.map
updmap [ERROR]: The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
updmap [ERROR]:  comicneue.map (in /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg)`

Answer (score -1):

1. Open terminal
2. Use the following command to search for the package name:

   `tlmgr search --global --file /comicneue.sty`

   This command searches for the package file in the TeX Live package
   repository.
3. If the package is found, use the following command to reinstall it:

   `sudo tlmgr install --reinstall comicneue`

   This command reinstalls the package from the TeX Live repository.

Comment: Thank you for your help John. I actually reinstalled the whole livetex package after uninstalling it and erasing config files, and everything works fine again.